# ASp.net MVC2 And Pluggable framework for ecommerce application

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp.net-mvc-2, plugins

I have recently started learning Asp.Net MVC2. Somehow i have developed an application using the same.

I want to develop an ecommerce application using which people can open their stores.

1.But I want the new module should independently be developed an incorporated with existing application.
2.As the application i want to be used by many users to create their own store. Will it be good if we use WCF or any service Layer.
3.For large dataset it takes a lot of time to load how we can make it load incrementally.

I am not sure about how the application should be designed for performance and extensibility.
If any book or reference can be provided that will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might want have a look at [Orchard Project](http://orchard.codeplex.com/).

Comment: but still need some .net Architect to answer this for performance in mind.